# Get string from dragged text view

Tags: java, android

I want to get the string from the text view that I dragged.

```
public void OnDropped(View zone, Object item)
{
    switch(zone.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button4:
            if (item instanceof String) 
                ((Button)zone).setText("DROP ITEM OK");// I want to getText But I dont know how to put in parameters 
            else    
                ((Button)zone).setText("DROP ITEM ERR");
            break;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`String buttonText = ((Button)zone).getText().toString();`

Comment: hi Im having a syntax error in buttonText thanks im a newbie in android

Comment: DropZoneListener dropZoneListener1 = new DropZoneListener()
    {

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
  @Override
        public void OnDropped(View zone, Object item)
        {
            Log.v("ddddd","drop time");
            switch(zone.getId())
            {
                case R.id.button4:
                    if (item instanceof String) 
    
                     String EditText = ((Button)zone).getText().toString();
                     
                    else    
                        ((Button)zone).setText("DROP ITEM ERR");

                    break;

Comment: What is the item object? Are you trying to set an EditText field to the text of a button?  What do you need to do with this string..?

Comment: object is in argumets in View.OnDropped im trying to get the get the string value of edittext that i dropped in button